# get request parameters in struts-config.xml in struts1

Tags: java, struts-1

In my action I would like to redirect to completely new application, I have configured my action as below in `struts-config.xml`

```
 <action path="/nameSpace/Myaction" type="MyActionClass" name="MyForm">
   <forward name="success" path="hereIwanttosendDynamic" redirect="true" />

 </action>
```

as you can see in above configuration I want to redirect to new application, And that application URL will be defined in my Action Class.

Now my doubt is Can I use `EL` in `Struts-config.xml` so that I can keep my new application URL in `request` and I would like to get that in `struts-config.xml`
Something like below

```
path="${redirectURL}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

The S1 config file is read at startup and does not store expressions that can be evaluated later.

But there's no reason to; redirect from the action.

Comment: Redirect from action ? You mean `responce.redirect("") ?` ? or any struts way I have seen struts1 not allowing me to redirect using `sendRedirect()` method How to solve this ?

Comment: @Babel Using the response and returning null from the action? Huh. Well, you could always put the URL in a request attribute, forward to a JSP, and do the redirect there. I'm not sure how a redirect could fail, though.

Comment: its working fine !! first time When I tried it was failed. Now its working fine thanks.